# "variety is the spice of life" in German

Tags: phrase-request, proverb

Ich suche ein deutsches Sprichwort, ähnlich zum Englischen [variety is the spice of life](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/variety-is-the-spice-of-life?q=variety%20is%20the%20spice%20of%20life&searchDictCode=all).

Ich finde im Wesentlichen nur eine [wörtliche Übersetzung](http://www.phrasen.com/uebersetze,Variety-is-the-spice-of-life,77898,e.html), welche aber meines Wissens nicht im Deutschen verwendet wird.
Ich habe den [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de) durchsucht, unter anderem nach *Abwechslung*, *Vielfalt* und *Variation*, aber es scheint nichts zu geben.

Ich beschränke mich nicht auf die Verwendung von *Würze*; mir geht es nur um die Kernaussage. Ich glaube aber, ich bin im Moment zu fixiert auf das Wort *Abwechslung*.
Daher meine Frage: Was gibt es da im Deutschen?

Comment: Ich meine, schon mal etwas wie "Vielfalt ist das Salz des Lebens" gehört zu haben, komme aber gerade nicht auf die wörtliche Formulierung.

Comment: https://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/102819

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn's in einem Kontext verwendet wird, wo es gerade darum geht, vielleicht etwas Neues auszuprobieren, könnte man sagen

> Öfter mal was Neues.

Als generelle Weisheit funktioniert das aber nicht.

Answer (score 6):

Natürlich gibt es "In der Abwechslung liegt die Würze des Lebens" o. ä., aber ob das nun wirklich idiomatisch ist, sei dahingestellt. Ein lateinisches Sprichwort ist mir noch bekannt, *varietas (oder: variatio) delectat,* aber auch das wird möglicherweise nicht universell verstanden.

Ich fürchte fast, dass es im Deutschen kein vollständig äquivalentes Idiom gibt. Man wird sich also mit einer Umschreibung (Vielfalt gibt dem Leben die Würze, die Mischung macht's, Abwechslung ist das halbe Leben) begnügen müssen.

Answer (score 3):

Meiner Meinung nach passt ‘Abwechslung macht das Leben süss.’ Mit süss ist nicht der süsse Geschmack gemeint sondern eben das, was im Englischen mit ‘spice’ gemeint ist.

Answer (score 2):

Im Duden Band 11 – *Redewendungen* findet man den bildungssprachlichen Ausspruch [*variatio delectat*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/variatio_delectat) (Abwechslung macht Freude)

> Nehmen wir doch mal einen Rheinwein statt des gewohnten Mosels – variatio delectat!

Laut Duden Band 12 – *Zitate und Aussprüche* findet sich der hierin ausgedrückte Gedanke, dass Abwechslung erfreut, schon bei dem griechischen Dramatiker Euripides (um 480–406 v. Chr.) in dessen Tragödie Orest. Darin rät Elektra ihrem kranken Bruder Orest, das Krankenlager zu verlassen, mit dem Hinweis: *Μεταβολή πάν των γλυχύ* (in wörtlicher Übersetzung: „Die Veränderung aller Dinge ist süß“).

Comment: Ich kenne Varietas delectat. Latein: Verschiedenheit erfreut.

Answer (score 1):

> Die Vielfalt / Mischung macht's.

ist zumindest eine oft gebrauchte Phrase.

Comment: Ja, gefällt mir ganz gut, wurde aber auch schon von Ingmar vorgeschlagen.

Comment: Oh, das hatte ich übersehen. Dann muss Ingmars Antwort besser formatiert werden ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe selbst noch mal gegoogelt und eine Reihe von Übersetzungen gefunden. Darunter war die Phrase "Es ist die Abwechslung, die...", welche ich durchaus als idiomatisch empfinde.

> Es ist die Abwechslung, die das Leben so lebenswert/interessant macht.
>   Es ist die Abwechslung, die das Leben bereichert/ausmacht/auszeichnet.

Comment: Als 'idiomatisch' gelten sprachinteressierten Kreisen Wortfolgen aus 'nicht frei kombinierten Wörtern', sondern aus mehr oder weniger fest aneinander gebundenen, und das nach Duden und Wiktionary so, dass sich ihre Gesamtbedeutung nicht aus den Bedeutungen der Einzelwörter ergibt. Idiome gehören zum Lexikon einer Sprache. 'Durchaus idiomatisch' kann ein sprachlicher Ausdruck nicht sein, aber er kann wirken, als wäre er ein Idiom. Die rhetorische Hervorhebung der 'Abwechslung' durch dieses 'es ist ..., die ...'  lässt den Satz nach Zitat oder Aphorismus aussehen und damit idiomhaft erscheinen.

Answer (score 0):

Ich verwende seit Jahren schlicht und ergreifend "Abwechslung ist die Würze des Lebens". Das entspricht natürlich Wort für Wort dem englischen Sprichwort. Ich finde diese Form aber recht gut - und kam interessanterweise bei der Suche nach der besten englischen Übersetzung dafür auf diese Seite hier.